# How to program a project to prevent a DDoS attack

Tags: javascript, c#, linux, security, ddos

I am trying to learn some things about computer security and I want to program a project that prevents a DDoS attack.

I fully understand DDoS attacks in theory and now I want to see some action.

I just wanna ask about what language should I use and what things should I implement for saving time. 
But of course I want to write a lot of parts of the code because education is the main thing here.

Comment: Expanding on @ThiagoLoureiro you should download a virtual machine  and put an ubuntu server (any server will work) then download a DDoS tool and fire at your virtual machine.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."*

Comment: Yes.. that is the idea, don't know why someone give the negative vote :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can program a .net Console application that listens on 'all ports' (or at least as many as you want to experiment with). The basic code to listen on multiple ports is here on MSDN https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/09828be4-6ac4-45ec-a116-508314dab793/listen-on-multiple-ports?forum=csharpgeneral

Your program would then presumably make identical calls to the destination server having examined the packets. However this is more like a Gateway than a proper firewall, as it cannot intercept IP traffic that wasnt originally sent to it (a firewall acts like a Switch in that all IP traffic flows through it whether it is the destination or not).

Answer (score -1):

you mean create a firewall ? :) Firewall is the tool to prevent DDoS attack, so you can start research about protocols, ports, then you can choose your language to develop. People like to use Java or Python for this purposes

Comment: btw I know tools like LOIC or other attacking tools like it and I know protocols from pluralsight. But I have a problem about finding a tool's code or some code that I can see what is going on. I know in theory but I just can't go more and write a code or start a code. I search about it but I didnt see anything so far.