# Request a change to a user's restricted attribute securely

Tags: security

I'm creating a web application where users earn points for using it (from time to time).
What is the best way to change the amount of points the user has in a safe way?

My first solution was to use a POST Request with the data in the body, but it would be easily circumvented since the user could open the console and send infinite copied requests and earn infinite points. And if I created a token, the user would copy that same token and reuse it until it is invalidated.

My second solution was to create a websocket that while the user maintains connection, he earns X points in X time but it would also be circumvented due to a false connection by the console

What to do in this situation?

Comment: While not *directly* specific to *your* personal situation, I would recommend reading my previous answer on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66234674/nodejs-security-issue-client-sending-request/66235074#66235074. It is pertinent to the core of what you're asking about here, which is: never trust the client, always perform sensitive calculations (like adding of points) only once the *trusted server* has verified that should happen.

Answer (score 0):

Use a POST request, and validate that the request is authentic on the back-end (based upon the criteria in which it is deemed 'reasonable' to award the points).

For example, if a user could only earn 1 point every 30 minutes, store when the user was last awarded points in a database, and then ensure that 30 minutes had passed since that point in time (again, server side).

You could also ensure that the user isn't getting more points than the should by checking the value of the points that they are being awarded, in a similar manner. Want one point at a time? Check that their existing score equals their target score plus one.

Comment: Ok, thats valid. But if the user knows (or discover) the interval (30 minutes), he could set a script that runs every 30 mins, earning points without using the website properly.